# Offline Dropbox & Sync Ideas

Tags: synchronization, dropbox

Is there any way to use Dropbox to sync selected local files? I like the idea of being able to switch some Dropbox folders to local. Because here, in Australia we still have data limits.

The scenario is that I need to sync Dropbox files on my iMac with my Macbook with only selected files syncing online (for client access). Because I work with a project code hierarchy, it's easier if all files (online & local) are in one folder. I usually just colour the completed jobs and archive by year.

I've tried Symbolic Links, but Dropbox just creates a copy. No idea how to implement Rsync, and I'm not sure what Git will involve. So just a note: I'm not all that savvy.

For now, all I need is to be able to effortlessly drag and drop files and let Dropbox do its thing when I turn Macbook on. The more I sync the better, because I forget things.

For later, I'm thinking of ways to fully sync my future Macbook Pro and iMac. I already sync BusyCal, Address Book, Billings etc., but there are a few flaws. Not happy with ChronoSync either. So... any thoughts on this one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you are asking.  If you are trying to sync files without using the Internet, because both computers are on the same network, then Dropbox has a feature for that called [LAN sync](http://www.dropbox.com/help/137).  If 2 machines are on the same LAN, Dropbox will sync files between them without using the Internet; instead, it will go through your local network.

Oftentimes, though, tools like [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy#SCP_program) are used for copying files around like this, but not necessarily for syncing.

Comment: Good news, but the file will still need to be synced online won't it? So that'll be an upload not a download...

But is there a way to just shut the online syncing off completely for certain folders ans just let it LAN sync instead? I go through a lot of design revisions, which I need to keep. And it's easier to just keep all jobs in the one Dropbox folder so I don't double up on project numbers. And, I really need to be able to switch off Dropbox when I'm mobile, because my broadband is limited to 1gb/month (and uploads are counted). So syncing a few files could easily use that up.

Comment: It seems your issue may just be with Dropbox then... I don't think there is a way to go around uploading to their servers if you are using Dropbox.  You could try mounting one machine as a networked file system, so that you can edit your files only there and they will be the same across both machines, but then when you move files around or save your files, I don't know if the tools are smart enough to stick to your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply "pause syncing" of your dropbox when you are going to be traveling and then renable syncing when you get back to office or to a hotel with wifi, etc...

Comment: Need proper explanation with respect to user's issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the revolutionary and free software Bittorrent Sync. Download it [here](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync). You can create your own personal cloud, without using Internet. Steps to use Bittorrent Sync

1. Download and install it on all the computers you want to sync to. Say A,B and C.
2. When asked if you already have a secret key. Select NO.
3. Lets assume that you want to sync your music folder with all these computers.
4. Open the software, select add folder.
5. Select your music folder, and click generate to create a long sequence of alphabets.
6. And click OK. Now you can see that folder in your list of folders.
7. Right click the folder and select copy secret, now paste this in notepad and save it in the pen drive or put it in your mail, so that you can access it on other computers.
8. Now go to other computer (B and C), create a folder to receive all the stuff, or if you've a folder which has content to be shared with others choose that.
9. Open Bittorrent Sync in B or C and click add a sync folder. Instead of clicking on generate this time copy paste the secret. And choose the destination folder
10. And you're done! Tada, sit back and watch the magic!
11. Also it creates a mesh network not star. Even though the secret was created at A, B and C can continue to sync if A is shutdown.
12. No Internet is required if all are connected in LAN.

Comment: Why a down vote?? Bittorrent Sync is a very popular software with more than 2 million downloads.